# proguard configuration error while using proguard-android-optimize.txt

Tags: android, proguard

i am trying to use proguard . i want to remove all logs so i have added

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {

public static *** v(...);
public static *** i(...);
public static *** w(...);
public static *** d(...);
public static *** e(...);
```

}

but this not working so i found that i have to use

```
  debug {

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
```

but this giving error but if  i use program-android.txt then it building but with program-android.txt logs are not getting disable

Comment: logs will be removed directly in your release build

Comment: but its not building also if i use optimise

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log { *; }
```